# Is it possible to use Visual C++ MFC function add-on in nodejs or golang?

Tags: c++, node.js, go, mfc, cgo

Currently, I have some visual c++ function using MFC. Can I use this functions as c++ addons in nodejs or golang?

To be specific, I need to somehow access to the OCX (ActiveX) object through my golang or nodejs code. So, I decided to write down the add-on using c++, but found it really difficult without using MFC/ATL things. So, can I use these MFC/ATL functions as addon/extension in nodejs or golang? Thanks!

Comment: You may use SWIG for C++ and Go: http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Go.html

Comment: You seem to be missing the obvious: ActiveX is based on COM, a language-agnostic ABI, that is callable from JavaScript (at least the `IDispatch` interface is). You are trying to write a wrapper for something, that is already consumable by your target platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can call ATL/MFC code from your addon C++ code but you cannot tie to ATL/MFC directly from nodejs/golang without your intermediate wrapper layer.

**Note**: either ***node-ffi*** for nodejs or ***cgo*** for golang are useful for integration with native code but will not help to call ATL/MFC directly just because both *node-ffi* and *cgo* target C calling convention (all C++ code has to be wrapped with **extern "C"** to be callable via *node-ffi*/*cgo*). So you still need to create C++ wrapper around ATL/MFC. Also when creating your addon/extension ensure ATL/MFC exceptions (or any other C++ exceptions) do not cross module boundaries.